# Measured frequency switching time different from cpuinfo_transition_latency

Tags: android, arm, scaling, frequency, measurement

I just performed some measurements on a Pandaboard ES (OMAP4460, ARM Cortex A9 with 1.2 GHz) to check how long cpu frequency changes take. I am running a Android 4.0.3 with a 3.0.8 Kernel. I modified the `omap_cpufreq_scale()` function in `omap2plus-cpufreq.c` to toggle a GPIO pin at the entry and the exit of the function and measured the time with an oscilloscope.

The measured switching times vary between `3.9ms` and `4.5ms` whereas a

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_transition_latency
```

reports `300000ns` which would be `0.3 ms`. Does anybody know why there is such a huge difference? How are the transition_latencies usually determined?

I couldn't find any timing values in the data sheets.

Update:

I found a small bug in the modified kernel module. The measured execution times lie in the range of `268µs` and `1210µs`, depending on the original and the selected frequency.

Comment: I just found the following line in omap2plus-cpufreq.c: /* FIXME: what's the actual transition time? */. So if anybody is interested, it lies in the range mentioned above.